# How to efficiently build multiple docker images from a large solution?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a large .NET solution and want to efficiently build multiple docker images from it for a few app projects.

The Dockerfile for the first project looks like this:

```
# Solution common build steps
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN setup-build-env.sh # Sets up additional NuGet feeds
RUN dotnet restore Linux.slnf

# Project specific build steps
RUN cd src/Category1/src/Project1 && dotnet publish -c Release -o publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/Category1/src/Project1/publish .
ENTRYPOINT dotnet Project1.dll
```

The parts up until including `RUN dotnet restore Linux.slnf` will be identical for every project image.

What I'm worried about most is the large (~400MB) `COPY . .` operation that seems to need to be repeated everytime this Dockerfile is built.

Each app project to be turned into a container references multiple projects in the solution, so just `COPY`ing the single project in question won't work.

How do I efficiently build multiple app project images from my large solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a custom image with the common part

### Common image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN setup-build-env.sh # Sets up additional NuGet feeds
RUN dotnet restore Linux.slnf
```

`docker build -t common.image:1.0 .`

### Project image

```
FROM common.image:1.0
RUN cd src/Category1/src/Project1 && dotnet publish -c Release -o publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/Category1/src/Project1/publish .
ENTRYPOINT dotnet Project1.dll
```

Obviously if the solution changes you must rebuild the common image

If ALL project has the SAME Dockerfile (change only the name) you can use the [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)